# Css for header,section and footer arrangement

Tags: html, css, header, height, footer

I have basic html code :

```
<header></header>
<main>
<nav></nav>
<section></section>
</main>
<footer></footer>
```

and I need css to have the header at the top, the footer at the bottom, the nav and the section between the header and footer, with the nav on the left and the section on the right.

As an example : https://fr.wikipedia.org/

But in the case where the main content is smaller than the screen size, I need to have the footer fixed on the bottom of the screen.

My CSS is something like that :

```
    header, nav, section, footer {
        padding: 1px 0;
    }

    header {
        background-color: lightcoral;
        text-align: center;
        background: #FF9900 url("/Content/Images/Etoile.png") 5px center no-repeat;
        background-size: 100px;
    }

    main {
        margin: auto;
    }

    nav {
        float: left;
        width: 15%;
        background-color: lightsalmon;
    }

    section {
        float : right;
        width : 85%;
        background-color: lightblue;
    }

    footer {
        background-color: lightgreen;
        text-align: center;
        clear: both;
    }
```

Could you help me please ?

Comment: Just use google - https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/

Comment: Can you post your current css you are having problems with to demonstrate the issue? Also, see [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: header, nav, section, footer {
       padding: 1px 0;}
header {
       background-color: lightcoral;
       text-align: center;
       background: #FF9900 url("/Content/Images/Etoile.png") 5px center no-repeat;
       background-size: 100px;}
main {
       margin: auto;}
nav {
       float: left;
       width: 15%;
       background-color: lightsalmon;}
section {
       float : right;
       width : 85%;
       background-color: lightblue;}
footer {
       background-color: lightgreen;
      text-align: center;
      clear: both;}

Sorry, I don't know how to put like code

Comment: @LuisP.A. Ok it seems good, but I need a header, and the nav on the left, and the section on the right. I will try with this solution

Comment: I already tried to search on Google. In fact it's 2h I'm looking for a solution. I tried all the things I found but none worked

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is create a simple page layout. You can check out [this resource](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp) for general information about how to do this, since there are multiple ways.

An example taken from the above resource is using the CSS `float` property. It should give you enough to start with for your solution.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.container {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

header, footer {
    padding: 1em;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    clear: left;
    text-align: center;
}

nav {
    float: left;
    max-width: 160px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}
   
nav ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

article {
    margin-left: 170px;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

<header>
   <h1>City Gallery</h1>
</header>
  
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">London</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Paris</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tokyo</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<article>
  <h1>London</h1>
  <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the  United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
  <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
</article>

<footer>Copyright &copy; W3Schools.com</footer>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I need the footer fixed at the bottom of the page in the case of the article content is smaller than the size of the page.

Comment: You can add "position: fixed;width: 100%;bottom: 0;" to the footer class. Is that what you mean?

Comment: At the moment, I have this : http://nsa38.casimages.com/img/2017/06/06/170606055428193894.png

And I want this :
http://nsa38.casimages.com/img/2017/06/06/170606055604140643.png

Comment: I don't want the footer always fixed, but just when the content of the article is smaller than the page's size

Comment: When the content is bigger than the size's page, I want to have the footer at the bottom of the "article"
http://nsa38.casimages.com/img/2017/06/06/17060605594679514.png

But when the content is smaller than the size's page, I want to have the footer fixe at the bottom of the page.
http://nsa38.casimages.com/img/2017/06/06/170606055604140643.png

Comment: I see. I think this demo illustrates what you need - http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/bottom-footer-demo.htm

Comment: Ok it works ! but still a small problem.
How can I ajust the nav size to the article size ?

At the moment : 
    article{
        padding : 10px;
        margin-left:15%;
        background-color: lightblue;
    }

    nav{
        float : left;
        width : 15%;
        background-color: lightsalmon; 
    }

http://nsa37.casimages.com/img/2017/06/07/170607110710102696.png
Why height : 100% doesnt work ?

Comment: A solution could be to put Display : flex for the container of the nav and article. But is there an other solution without flex box ?